# Which is higher John's new salary or Brad's salary or equal?

Tags: calculation-puzzle

John's salary is 30% less than Brad's salary. John left work and joined a new institution, where his salary was 30% higher than his old salary.

Which is higher John's new salary or Brad's salary or equal?

is the answer equal?

Answer (score 2):

Let J be John’s salary and let B be Brad’s salary.

Then,

> Since John’s salary is 30% less than Brad’s, J(old) = 0.7B. However, John’s new salary is 30% more than John’s old salary, so J(new) = 1.3(J(old)) = 1.3(0.7B) = 0.91B.

Therefore

> John’s new salary is less than (it’s 91% of) Brad’s salary.